# Strange behavior of DiracDelta

Tags: functions

On Mathematica 11.1.1.0 on Mac OS X86, I found the following behavior of DiracDelta:

```
DiracDelta[x - a] /. x -> a
(* DiracDelta[0] *)

DiracDelta[x - 1/5] /. x -> 1/5
(* 5 DiracDelta[0] *)
```

Why there is an additional factor 5 in front of DiracDelta[0]?

Comment: DiracDelta[0] has no sense. I will submit that bug.

Comment: Indeterminate should be performed in both the cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For rational numbers `r`, `DiracDelta[x-r]` evaluates:

```
DiracDelta[x - 1/5]
```

> 5 DiracDelta[-1 + 5 x]

Recall that [`DiracDelta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta) is a distribution, and is only well defined when it occurs inside of an integral. The two versions are equivalent when used inside of an integral:

```
Integrate[x^2 DiracDelta[x - a], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] /. a->1/5
Integrate[x^2 DiracDelta[x - 1/5], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
Integrate[x^2 (5 DiracDelta[-1 + 5 x]), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> 1/25
>
> 1/25
>
> 1/25

**Addendum**

You might be curious about why [`DiracDelta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta) evaluates in this way. Note that distributions (of which [`DiracDelta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta) is one) form a real vector space. This means that Mathematica needs to be able to add [`DiracDelta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta) objects that represent the same distribution, even if their arguments are different. Since Mathematica canonicalizes [`DiracDelta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta) objects with exact numeric coefficients, the following examples produce a single [`DiracDelta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta) object:

```
DiracDelta[x-1/2] + 2 DiracDelta[2x-1]
DiracDelta[x-1/π] + π DiracDelta[Pi x - 1]
```

> 4 DiracDelta[-1 + 2 x]
>
> 2 π DiracDelta[-1 + π x]

Converting expressions to a canonical (or normal) form is an essential part of all symbolic algebra programs.

You also might ask why the canonical form of `DiracDelta[x-1/5]` is `5 DiracDelta[5x-1]` instead of just the original `DiracDelta[x - 1/5]`, but that is a question whose answer I do not know.

Comment: While this is all very much true, do sympathize with the OP's bafflement over this rather obscure evaluation behaviour for `DiracDelta`.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I gave an update explaining why DiracDelta objects evaluate to a canonical form.

Answer (score 0):

```
Trace[DiracDelta[x - 1/5] /. x -> 1/5]
(*{{{{{{1/5,1/5},1/5,1/5},-(1/5),-(1/5)},x-1/5,-(1/5)+x},DiracDelta[-(1/5)+x],5 DiracDelta[-1+5 x]},{{{1/5,1/5},1/5,1/5},x->1/5,x->1/5},5 DiracDelta[-1+5 x]/. x->1/5,5 DiracDelta[-1+5/5],{{{5/5,1},-1+1,0},DiracDelta[0]},5 DiracDelta[0]}*)
```